# Using a portable generator cord for 50 amps

Tags: generator

I have a Westinghouse WGen9500 portable generator. The grounding prong space where the 4 prong end fits in has one flat edge.
Can I put a plug with a round grounding prong into it?

Comment: The D shape should only be on the cover/housing(plastic part) of the receptacle.  I never gave it much thought if the plug fitted in, it was good.  Usually it is the other prong shapes that matter if it the right plug for that receptacle.

Comment: Can you identify your plug/socket in a lineup? Or look for a number such as NEMA 14-xx. https://www.bsaelectronics.com/pages/nema-plug-and-outlet-chart.   https://www.lockingpowercords.com/topic/13-nema-locking-chart.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Based on a websearch for "Westinhouse WGen9500" I got this: https://westinghouseoutdoorpower.com/products/wgen9500-generator which shows a L14-30R receptacle. This receptacle can only take an L14-30P plug. These receptacle and plug are 30 amp rating. So you cannot put a 50 amp plug in this 30 amp receptacle.

On the other hand, the generator has a 14-50R "RV-style" receptacle rated for 50 amps. This receptacle takes a 14-50P plug.

[image: Westinghouse generator plate]
(picture from Westinghouse website above)

In either case, get a cord with the correct plug on it for the receptacle you want to use. Don't try to modify or jam a plug in that doesn't go in relatively easily.

Per a comment from @crip659, if you're worried about the ground pin on the 14-50 being round or U-shaped: as long as the plug is a UL-listed 14-50 it won't matter what shape the ground pin is, both will fit correctly.

Comment: I think OP is wondering if they need a D shape ground prong to go into the D shape hole.  I never noticed if ground prongs had a D shape, they all looked round to me, and the plugs fitted in.  At that amount of power I like plugs that need a decent push to go in, if the right size/shape.

Comment: Good point, @crip659, thanks! I'll add something about that.

Comment: RV style? And here I thought it was for plugging your electric range into...

Comment: An electric dryer would work, too!